# if-else condition in C

Tags: c, if-statement

**In C language, what is the result of `x=0` if I put it in `if-else` condition? if it is represent `false` or if this assignment is finished, then represent `true`?**

my colleague write code as:

```
if(condition = 0)
{
    //do process A
}
else
{
    // do process B
}
```

obviously, this code is wrong, I know it should be `condition == 0` or `((condition=foo()) == 0)` but my assumption is program should always do process A because i think `if(condition = 0)` should always return true since this is set value `0` to variable `condition` and this set process should be true. However, program always do process B, that means `if` use the variable `condition` value and my assumption is wrong.

Then I did a another test code:

```
if(condition = 2) //or other none-zero value
{
    //do process A
}
else
{
    // do process B
}
```

this time, program always do process A.

My question is why `if-else` condition does not use the operation value of condition but use the left variable after setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you assign 0 to variable condition it becomes false as 0 represents false and any non-zero value represents true.so, when you assign 0 else condition is executed and when you assign 2 condition represents a true statement so, it executes...

```
if(condition = 0)
```

after assigning value 0 to condition it becomes

```
if(condition)
```

and as it is false, it doesn't execute.but, when condition = 2, it works in the same way and become true .so, the if condition is executed then.

Comment: but I think the assign operation should return `true`

Comment: why it should return true ? it will return true for all the values except only for 0.

Comment: I mean the assign operation is successfully done, and no error return during assignment

Comment: @HowChen Assignment in C can't possibly result in an error (well, it could result in undefined behavior, but that's undefined). Returning a success/fail would be meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

You use wrong operator.

a = 10;

The "equals" operator means "assign value to".

Now to compare two operands, a and b, to see if a = b, you use another operand.
That operand is double equals (==).

```
if(variable == 0)
{
    //do process A
}
else
{
    // do process B
}
```

Now look.

If the variable with name "variable" has value = 8 that is not equal to 0, 
thus the whole "variable == 0" expression if FALSE.
So proccess B will run.

If otherwise variable is equal to 0 indeed, proccess A will be executed because "variable == 0" is true.

It's like:

```
if(EXPRESSION)
{
    // EXPRESSION IS TRUE
}
else
{
    //EXPRESSION IS FALSE
}
```

Got it? :)

Comment: I know how to use `if-else`, pls look my question, I need to know why if use condition value 0 but not use the operation result of a assignment

Comment: You got an expression in a parenthesis. That expression can be something (a == b) or just (b). If you now assign (b = 2) it is not 0 so not false. So it is true. Thus (b=2) is equal to just (b) with value different than 0. So it returns always true. Hope this helped you. That 2 assigns different than false value really...

Answer (score 2):

In C, assignment is an expression that returns the set value; i.e. `x = 2` will result in 2.

This allows you to do something like this:

```
unsigned char ch;
while((ch = readFromFile(f)) != EOF) {
    // do something with ch
}
```

It also allows you to shoot yourself in the foot if you accidentally mistype `==` as `=`, which is why this 'feature' doesn't appear in a lot of other languages.

In your first loop, the expression `condition = 0` will always result in `0`, causing the `else` branch to be taken. Similarly, `condition = 2` results in `2`, which causes the true branch to be taken.

Comment: but what is operation the result of `x=2`, `true` of `false`?

Comment: @HowChen read the first sentence of this post. The result of an assignment is the variable that was assigned to. `if (x = 0)` is the same as `x = 0; if (x)`

Comment: it is `2`.  And when an integer appears in an `if` statement, then `0` means `false`, and anything not `0` means `true`!  That's an important fact about C.